# Creating a pdf file with a python script

Tags: python, flask, cron

I am trying to make a python script that will generate a pdf file everyday at midnight with cron. The cron part works fine. The problem is that when I execute my python script the pdf file doesn't get stored where I want it to be stored. I am getting the correct message (Loading page (1/2) Printing pages (2/2) Done) from the render_template function but the pdf file just isn't there. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Here's my python code:

```
import os, subprocess, re, datetime
from conf import config
import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template, make_response
import pdfkit

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')
app.debug=True

@app.route('/')
def main():
    cur_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    cur_year = cur_date.year
    cur_month = cur_date.month
    cur_day = cur_date.day
    date_str = str(cur_year) + "/" + str(cur_month) + "/" + str(cur_day)
    with app.app_context():
        x = render_template("daily_update.htm")
        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(x, False)
        response = make_response(pdf)
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=output.pdf"
        return (response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Is the pdf fine when you browse the endpoint? how is your cron job? Are you using something like `curl http://<endpoint> -o <destination_file>`?

Comment: this is my cron job: "echo '* * * * *' python /home/matthew/L3S/pigc/Routes/../modifications.py | crontab -" But I am currently just executing my python script in the terminal like this: python3 modifications.py

Comment: I am manually executing my script so I'm not quite sure how  to browse to the endpoint as the script is only executed once

Comment: `I'm not quite sure how to browse to the endpoint` Are you actually planning on running this as a web-app, or is this exclusively a command line script (launched with cron) which needs to take advantage of Flask's `render_template` function?

Comment: @v25 I would like to just be able to launch this script once every 24 hours thanks to cron so that my clients have the daily pdf stored in their system but maybe I'm not doing this the right way, if you have any ideas or advice I will gladly listen.

Comment: I Have done a PDF create project in python flask and a simple UI in html, jinja.  Here is my project github repository check it: https://github.com/Fasil005/Text_Appending_-_PDF_Creater.git

Comment: @FasilK the problem I am facing is that I have to automaticaly create these pdf files then save them on the client's machine without opening them and without the client interfering in any way so I can't have any buttons calling functions or anything, I have no idea how I could save these pdfs on the client's side basicaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to just be able to launch this script once every 24 hours thanks to cron so that my clients have the daily pdf stored in their system but maybe I'm not doing this the right way

I think the problem is you're structuring this as a classic Flask app, because you need to make use of the `render_template` function; but don't actually need the endpoint served by the `@app.route` decorator, nor the web-friendly response with the `Content-Disposition` headers, etc.

A simpler way to do this may be:

```
import os, subprocess, re, datetime
import datetime
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pdfkit

def make_pdf(filename, template_folder):

    # Define the app here (explained later)
    app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=template_folder)

    cur_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    cur_year = cur_date.year
    cur_month = cur_date.month
    cur_day = cur_date.day
    date_str = str(cur_year) + "/" + str(cur_month) + "/" + str(cur_day)

    with app.app_context():
        x = render_template("daily_update.htm", DATE=date_str)

    print(x) # `x` is now the string you want to write to the PDF

    # `pdfkit.from_string` has native ability to write to a file:
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(x, filename)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_pdf('output.pdf','templates')
```

I mocked a sample template at `templates/daily_update.htm` with the contents:

```
Sample template, the date is {{DATE}}
```

This results in a PDF called `output.pdf` with the contents:

```
Sample template, the date is 2021/8/30
```

---

Also note, that by defining the `app` variable inside the `make_pdf` function, allows you to specify `template_folder` when you call the function.

So you could do some clever stuff, if you wanted to create a template folder per customer, for their own custom templates, then call with something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    make_pdf('special_customer_report.pdf', 'special_customer_templates')
```

---

UDPATE:

> I have no idea how I could save these pdfs on the client's side basicaly

This works if you actually deploy this app to the clients machine.  If you're thinking or running this centrally, and somehow getting the PDFs out to the client's machine there's lots of variables / design decisions there which are kinda outwith the context of this question.